# How to insert text using substitute and regex?

Tags: regular-expression, search, substitute, replace, quickfix

Honestly I can't read regex for now.

I have quick-fix list and I have a hunch that this can be done with regex but I don't know how.

I want this:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable)
@ViewChild('text 1')
@ViewChild('text2')
```

to convert to this:

```
@ViewChild(MatTable, {static: false})
@ViewChild('text 1', {static: false})
@ViewChild('text2', {static: false})
```

Is it possible to do it with substitute and regex? If it is how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you'll need to apply a substitution command `:s` [`:h :s`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3As).

First you need to define the range: either `%` if you want that applied to all the lines in the buffer or `'<,'>` to apply to the lines which are visually selected. Assuming this is the first case your command will start with `:%s/`

Now the pattern: here the simplest solution is to say "I want to replace every closing parenthesis with some text". So `:%s/)/` no need for a regex you only match a regular `)` character.

Then we add the new text `, {static: false})` note that as we replace the original `)` we need to add it to the replacement text. So `:%s/)/, {static: false})/`.

Note that you could also have changed you replacement text so that you reuse the matched text: `:%s/)/, {static: false}&/`.

You probably also want to read [`:h pattern`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#pattern)

*EDIT* As Ben pointed out in the comments, you actually want to apply the substitution on lines referenced in the quickfix list. To do so you will need to use [`:h :cdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Acdo) to apply the command on every referenced lines and you will need to remove the range information. So the final command should be:

```
:cdo s/)/, {static: false})/
```

Comment: Ohh, it never came on my mind to use the ```)``` as the starting point. BTW thanks for the solution.

Comment: You're completely right Ben, I forgot this information when I wrote my answer, I'll update.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble yeah, I also learned about cdo yesterday